Episode of a sci-fi series about a salesman who loses the ability to understand English
I'm trying to identify and find an episode of a Sci-Fi series that I thought was either Amazing Stories or Tales from the Dark Side or The Twilight Zone, etc., in which a salesman of products with almost impossible to pronounce names begins to forget how to speak his own language.  It begins with his wife telling him that his son didn't eat his "dinosaur" today.  The salesman asks her to repeat what she said and the wife repeats the sentence, now with "lunch" replacing "dinosaur".
By the end of the episode, the man can't communicate at all, even though everyone is speaking English words... just in combinations which are unintelligible to him.
In the last scene, his child is in the emergency room with the emergency room staff asking the man questions, presumably about the child's condition, which he's unable to understand, much less answer.  He stands there helplessly as his wife takes over, also speaking unintelligibly to him by this time, and after a look of wonder and concern for her husband before turning to the hospital staff for the more immediate and pressing issue of her child's illness.
It was a fascinating episode which I would very much like to see again.  Can anyone help me identify the show series and episode?

Likely a duplicate of "TV episode about man who has the meanings of words change"

I believe this was "Wordplay", the first segment of the second episode of the first season (1985–86) of The New Twilight Zone, which you can see here. The 'dinosaur' and emergency room details match.




Lol. Yours is a perfectly fine answer. There's no sense having two that are basically identical :-)

Now if you'll excuse me, I'm late for my dinosaur,
